# Is selenium IDE testcase, an example for keyword-driven test methodology

Tags: selenium-ide

The test cases in  Selenium IDE, look similar to the test cases written in files in keyword-driven test frameworks. 
So is it correct to say, Selenium IDE is a tool built on the concepts of keyword-driven testing

Answer (score 0):

Though it seems like a keyword (Click,type,sendkeys) driven framework it is not a keyword driven framework. Logically in a keyword driven framework common tasks with respect to a specific functionality are grouped under basic keywords and these keywords are then combined to achieve a complex functionality or business flow.

According to me Selenium IDE which provides us a record and playback option is a type of linear script / structured framework that allows even a non-technical user to easily perform his tests in sequentially ordered flow. Of course , these scripts can be customized in future if required but the ultimate goal here is to automate the tests with less/no technical knowledge.